# How to simplify query from excel to sqlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite

How to achieved the same result in sqlite?

In excel I have this which count the headcount base on assigned letter code per day:
[image]

Here's my excel formula: `=SUMIF(G$2:G$5,E9,$E$2:$E$5)`
[image]

In my Sqlite database I have 3 tables:

```
TABLE 1
+----------------+---------------+--------+
| ID | status_name | status_code | status |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 1  | Available   | A           | true   |
+------------------+-------------+--------+
| 2  | HalfDay     | H           | true   |
+------------------+-------------+--------+
| 3  | On Leave    | OL          | true   |            
+------------------+-------------+--------+
| 4  | Restday     | R           | true   |            
+------------------+-------------+--------+
| 5  | Vacation    | V           | true   |            
+------------------+-------------+--------+

TABLE 2
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| EmployeeName | Site  | Shift | Team | JobTitle |
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Steve        | Bldg1 | Night | N1   | Doctor   |
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Dave         | Bldg1 | Night | N2   | Nurse    | 
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Jack         | Bldg1 | Night | N2   | Nurse    |
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Jacob        | Bldg2 | Day   | D1   | Doctor   |
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| Noah         | Bldg2 | Day   | D2   | Nurse    | 
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+
| MAX          | Bldg2 | Day   | D2   | Nurse    | 
+--------------+-------+-------+------+----------+

TABLE 3
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| JobsType | Site  | Shift | Team | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Doctor   | Bldg1 | Night | N1   | A   | H   | A   | A   | OL  | A   | A   |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Nurse    | Bldg1 | Night | N2   | A   | H   | H   | A   | A   | A   | A   |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Doctor   | Bldg2 | Day   | D1   | H   | A   | H   | H   | A   | A   | OL  |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Nurse    | Bldg1 | Night | N2   | A   | H   | H   | A   | A   | A   | A   |
+----------+-------+-------+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

By using the 3 tables above how could I achieved this result in query?

```
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| STATUS TYPES | SUN | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI | SAT |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Available    | 5   | 4   | 4   | 5   | 5   | 6   | 5   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| HalfDay      | 1   | 5   | 5   | 1   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| On Leave     | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 1   | 0   | 1   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Restday      | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| Vacation     | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

So far I've come this;

```
    SELECT DISTINCT M.status_name, M.status_code, A.SUN, count(*),count(*) FROM TABLE3 M LEFT join TABLE2 A ON M.status_code= A.SUN LEFT join TABLE2 B ON (A.Team = B.Team AND A.Shift = B.Shift AND A.Site = B.Site)  
WHERE M.product_status = 1  
GROUP BY M.status_name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, generate a test database (With a couple of helpful indexes):

```sql
CREATE TABLE status(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, status_name TEXT, status_code TEXT, status TEXT);
INSERT INTO status VALUES(1,'Available','A','true');
INSERT INTO status VALUES(2,'HalfDay','H','true');
INSERT INTO status VALUES(3,'On Leave','OL','true');
INSERT INTO status VALUES(4,'Restday','R','true');
INSERT INTO status VALUES(5,'Vacation','V','true');
CREATE TABLE employees(EmployeeName TEXT, Site TEXT, Shift TEXT, Team TEXT, JobTitle TEXT);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Steve','Bldg1','Night','N1','Doctor');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Dave','Bldg1','Night','N2','Nurse');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Jack','Bldg1','Night','N2','Nurse');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Jacob','Bldg2','Day','D1','Doctor');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES('Noah','Bldg2','Day','D2','Nurse');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES('MAX','Bldg2','Day','D2','Nurse');
CREATE TABLE schedule(JobsType TEXT, Site TEXT, Shift TEXT, Team TEXT, SUN TEXT, MON TEXT, TUE TEXT, WED TEXT, THU TEXT, FRI TEXT, SAT TEXT);
INSERT INTO schedule VALUES('Doctor','Bldg1','Night','N1','A','H','A','A','OL','A','A');
INSERT INTO schedule VALUES('Nurse','Bldg1','Night','N2','A','H','H','A','A','A','A');
INSERT INTO schedule VALUES('Doctor','Bldg2','Day','D1','H','A','H','H','A','A','OL');
INSERT INTO schedule VALUES('Nurse','Bldg1','Night','N2','A','H','H','A','A','A','A');
CREATE INDEX employees_idx ON employees(JobTitle, Site, Shift, Team);
CREATE INDEX status_idx_code ON status(status_code);
```

This query:

```sql
SELECT st.status_name, st.status_code
     , sum(sc.SUN = st.status_code) AS SUN
     , sum(sc.MON = st.status_code) AS MON
     , sum(sc.TUE = st.status_code) AS TUE
     , sum(sc.WED = st.status_code) AS WED
     , sum(sc.THU = st.status_code) AS THU
     , sum(sc.FRI = st.status_code) AS FRI
     , sum(sc.SAT = st.status_code) AS SAT
FROM status AS st
JOIN schedule AS sc ON st.status_code IN (sc.SUN, sc.MON, sc.TUE, sc.WED
                                        , sc.THU, sc.FRI, sc.SAT)
JOIN employees AS e ON sc.JobsType = e.JobTitle AND sc.Site = e.Site
                   AND sc.Shift = e.Shift AND sc.Team = e.Team
GROUP BY st.status_name, st.status_code
ORDER BY st.status_name, st.status_code;
```

will produce

```
status_name  status_code  SUN         MON         TUE         WED         THU         FRI         SAT       
-----------  -----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
Available    A            5           1           1           5           5           6           5         
HalfDay      H            1           5           5           1           0           0           0         
On Leave     OL           0           0           0           0           1           0           1
```

How it works:

For each row in the status table, join each row in the schedule table that has that status for at least one day, and then join all rows from the employee table that match each schedule row's type of job (With this sample data, that results in a total of 14 rows being generated). Then group all the rows on the status, and for each day, add up the number of rows in that group where the schedule code for that day matches the status.